# How to receive the messages from other users while the user is typing his message?

Tags: sockets

I need to build a chat room using C++, which will run in command prompt. 
How to divide the screen into two parts so that I can receive the messages from other users while the user is typing his message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pointer: you can use `ncurses`:

1. Use `getmaxx(stdscr)` and `getmaxy(stdscr)` to discover terminal width and height (width is the number of columns, height is the number of rows).
2. Use `newwin(lines/2, cols, 0, 0);` to place an upper window. Then use it again to place a second window below (but this time change first zero to `lines/2`.

For a complete documentation, [go here](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html).

Note that ncurses is a C library.